# Printing of Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, printing

I have created a GUI in Java and it have one button name Print....On printing the GUI it get print properly but it takes very long time to print....please help me of how to reduce the waiting time...Thank you

I am using the following Code for printing

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (ae.getSource() == bprint)
    {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        System.out.println("here");
        if (ok)
        {
            try
            {
                job.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException
{

    if (page > 0)
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    p1.printAll(g);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes a long time to print.  You reduce the running time by performing the printing in a separate thread.

You have to pass the JFrame (to print the whole GUI) or the Swing component you wish to print to the printing thread.

```
    printButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            new Thread(new PrintActionListener(frame)).start();
        }
    });
```

Here's my printer thread

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.ggl.sudoku.solver.view.SudokuFrame;

public class PrintActionListener implements Runnable {

    private SudokuFrame frame;

    public PrintActionListener(SudokuFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final BufferedImage image = createPanelImage();

        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintable(new ImagePrintable(printJob, image));

        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException prt) {
                prt.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage createPanelImage() {
        JPanel panel = frame.getSudokuPanel();
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(),
                panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        panel.paint(g);
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }

    public class ImagePrintable implements Printable {

        private double          x, y, width;

        private int             orientation;

        private BufferedImage   image;

        public ImagePrintable(PrinterJob printJob, BufferedImage image) {
            PageFormat pageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
            this.x = pageFormat.getImageableX();
            this.y = pageFormat.getImageableY();
            this.width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
            this.orientation = pageFormat.getOrientation();
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
                throws PrinterException {
            if (pageIndex == 0) {
                int pWidth = 0;
                int pHeight = 0;
                if (orientation == PageFormat.PORTRAIT) {
                    pWidth = (int) Math.min(width, (double) image.getWidth());
                    pHeight = pWidth * image.getHeight() / image.getWidth();
                } else {
                    pHeight = (int) Math.min(width, (double) image.getHeight());
                    pWidth = pHeight * image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();
                }
                g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, pWidth, pHeight, null);
                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            } else {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
        }

    }

}
```